# Excel Extract fixed length amount from cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel Extract fixed length amount form cell

Imported data to one column (A)
Need to Extract the Amount from Start Position 20 and Field Length 11

Comment: Use the MID function

Comment: Worked great - Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mid(), something like

```
=mid(A1,20,11)
```

If the source is in cell A1.

Not tested as I am on a smartphone...